# Get a list of the possible FTP servers that are available in the Debian repositories?

Tags: linux, networking, debian, virtual-machine, ftp

This may or may not be an extremely simple question that I am completely overlooking, but I have been working on assignment for my Networking Class. For this assignment, we are to open two Debian VMs (one being a clone of the other) that serve the places of a 'pc' and 'server'. **In our 'server' VM we are to acquire a list of FTP servers currently available in the Debian Repositories(?).**

While this question sounds simple, I have not been able to find a solution online, nor get help from the professor. It has not been taught to us either. It probably also helps that I am not that adept with Linux based machines.

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated!

**What I currently know:**

- The bolded question is word for the word the question assigned to us, so I am unable to clarify further what is being asked, which is why I am here (professor will not clarify either as he believes this is enough).
- This is not about programming, but rather using a FTP since the steps following deal with sharing a file between the two VMs via FTPs.
- The VMs we are currently using were set-up by the professor, so it could be possible there is a saved list of FTPs in the 'Debian Repository' but I am unsure how to access those.

This is also a repost as I was informed to repost it due to belonging it the wrong place, so in a previous discussion with [Bodo](https://superuser.com/users/992527/bodo) it was noted the meaning of the question can be interpreted many different ways, which I understand. This question is quite vague and I do not understand it myself.
It was also asked if this question had to deal with writing some kind of software, which it does not.
Furthermore, it was also asked by Bodo if the question could be referring to FTPs currently reachable by the machine, which I do believe is possible. So this could be a route to explore. But I am unaware how to check this either.

**Update**

After some discussion with fellow students, I was informed to use **'sudo apt-cache search ftp | grep -i server'**. This command displayed the following:

> apt-cacher - Caching proxy server for Debian/Ubuntu software repositories
>
> atftpd - advanced TFTP server
>
> awffull - web server log analysis program
>
> bzr-upload - Bazaar plugin for uploading to web servers
>
> pawserv - CERNLIB data analysis suite - distributed PAW and file transfer servers
>
> dnsmasq - Small caching DNS proxy and DHCP/TFTP server
>
> dnsmasq-base - Small caching DNS proxy and DHCP/TFTP server
>
> erlang-inets - Erlang/OTP Internet clients and servers
>
> libghc-ftphs-dev - FTP Client and Server Library for Haskell
>
> libghc-ftphs-doc - FTP Client and Server Library for Haskell; documentation
>
> libghc-ftphs-prof - FTP Client and Server Library for Haskell; profiling libraries
>
> ftpwatch - Notifies you of changes on remote ftp servers
>
> gadmintools - GTK+ server administration tools (meta-package)
>
> gatling - high performance web server and file server
>
> gesftpserver - sftp server submodule for OpenSSH
>
> globus-gridftp-server-dbg - Globus Toolkit - Globus GridFTP Server Debug Symbols
>
> globus-gridftp-server-progs - Globus Toolkit - Globus GridFTP Server Programs
>
> libglobus-gridftp-server-dbg - Globus Toolkit - Globus GridFTP Server Debug Symbols
>
> libglobus-gridftp-server-dev - Globus Toolkit - Globus GridFTP Server Development Files
>
> libglobus-gridftp-server6 - Globus Toolkit - Globus GridFTP Server
>
> libglobus-gridftp-server-control-dbg - Globus Toolkit - Globus GridFTP Server Library Debug Symbols
>
> libglobus-gridftp-server-control-dev - Globus Toolkit - Globus GridFTP Server Library Development Files
>
> libglobus-gridftp-server-control0 - Globus Toolkit - Globus GridFTP Server Library
>
> inetutils-ftpd - File Transfer Protocol server
>
> libfax-hylafax-client-perl - simple Perl client for HylaFAX fax server
>
> libnet-server-perl - extensible, general perl server engine
>
> libnet-sftp-sftpserver-perl - Secure File Transfer Protocol Server
>
> libnet-tftp-perl - Perl module for accessing TFTP servers
>
> libnet-tftpd-perl - Perl extension for Trivial File Transfer Protocol Server
>
> ftpd - File Transfer Protocol (FTP) server
>
> ftpd-ssl - FTP server with SSL encryption support
>
> mysecureshell - SFTP Server with ACL
>
> tftpd - Trivial file transfer protocol server
>
> nordugrid-arc-gridftpd - ARC GridFTP server
>
> obex-data-server - D-Bus service for OBEX client and server side functionality
>
> openssh-sftp-server - secure shell (SSH) sftp server module, for SFTP access from remote machines
>
> pure-ftpd - Secure and efficient FTP server
>
> pure-ftpd-common - Pure-FTPd FTP server (Common Files)
>
> pure-ftpd-ldap - Secure and efficient FTP server with LDAP user authentication
>
> pure-ftpd-mysql - Secure and efficient FTP server with MySQL user authentication
>
> pure-ftpd-postgresql - Secure and efficient FTP server with PostgreSQL user >authentication
>
> python-pyftpdlib - Python FTP server library
>
> python3-pyftpdlib - Python FTP server library
>
> sn - Small NNTP server for leaf sites
>
> tftpd-hpa - HPA's tftp server
>
> util-vserver - user-space tools for Linux-VServer virtual private servers
>
> vsftpd - lightweight, efficient FTP server written for security
>
> vsftpd-dbg - lightweight, efficient FTP server written for security (debug)
>
> webfs - lightweight HTTP server for static content
>
> publicfile-installer - installer package for the publicfile HTTP and FTP server

And seeing as a particular item is listed that is needed for a later step in the assignment (pure-ftpd), I believe this is the list I am looking for.

Comment: Instead of simply copying the somewhat unclear question text you should add all information based on the comments in the now deleted question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66704521 . (I still have a copy of the comments.) To me it is not even clear if the question is about programming something to check the availability of FTP servers (In this case it would belong to stackoverflow.com.) or about using the Debian package management. Without improvement it is likely that the question might get closed because of missing details or clarity.

Comment: @Bodo Okay, understood. I apologize if this is frustrating for you to read or try to follow, I am just as frustrated since I have no idea what I am to do.

 As for the previous comments, I added what I believe was important from our discussion as well as a list containing as much as I know. Also, when it comes to asking the professor, I attempted to and believes the question to be self explanatory. So I am kinda stuck. It wasn't discussed ever, nor is it in our lecture notes. 

And I am unsure where to post this as I have been told to post it here and to delete the other one.

Comment: The recommendation to post here was based on your unclear question. It can be understood as a question about using or configuring a Debian system. Then here is the right place. If it was about programming a script or similar, then it would belong to stackoverflow.com. You wrote "the steps following deal with sharing a file between the two VMs via FTPs". Showing the following steps might help to clarify your task. Is the original assignment in English? If not, then maybe showing the exact text in its original language might make it more clear for someone who speaks the language.

Comment: Assuming the task is about choosing and installing FTP server and client, do you know how to install software on a Debian system or how to check what is already installed? Please explain this in your question including the names of the tools you would use.

Answer (score 0):

There is this question on Server Fault: [*How do I get a list of packages that “Provides” something" using `dpkg`?*](https://serverfault.com/q/364608)

[One of the answers](https://serverfault.com/a/364612) uses `aptitude` instead of `dpkg` (or `apt`, `apt-cache` or whatever). The point is the `search` feature of `aptitude` allows you to easily search by the "Provides" field. Any well-maintained FTP server package should report `ftp-server` in this field.

```
aptitude search '~Pftp-server'
```

Notes:

- You may need to install `aptitude` first.
- Don't forget to `aptitude update` (or equivalently `apt-get update`) before you search.
- The method works because there is a [virtual package](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-binary.html#s-virtual-pkg) named `ftp-server`. See *Debian Policy Manual*, *Declaring relationships between packages*, [*Virtual packages - Provides*](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html#virtual-packages-provides).
- `ftp-server` means FTP, not SFTP nor TFTP. There is a virtual package named `tftp-server`, so in theory you can easily find these; but in practice it seems some TFTP server packages don't use the "Provides" field.
- Similarly it's possible some FTP server packages don't use the field and my command won't find them. Your approach with `apt-cache search … | grep …` may find them, but I can see it prints more than FTP servers; some heuristics and/or insight (with `apt-cache show …`) is needed to spot false positives. My command should not print false positives, everything it gives you should really be an FTP server. So my command may give you too few results but the results are firm; while your command gives you more results, but some of them should be discarded.